# Auto fill on input with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

if user input this field

```
<input class="form-control" type="date"
       name="tgl_selesai"
       value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_inq['tgl_selesai'],
                                      ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>"
       size="32"><br>
```

Then automaticly this field will be fill

```
<label>Status Inquiry:</label><br>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="Closed"
           <?php
               if (!(strcmp(htmlentities($row_inq['status'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'), "Closed"))) {
                   echo "checked=\"checked\"";
                  }
           ?>> Closed
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="On Progres"
           <?php
               if (!(strcmp(htmlentities($row_inq['status'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'),"On Progres"))) {
                   echo "checked=\"checked\"";
                 }
           ?>> On Progres
</label>
```

if user input = closed

Comment: @Amessihel if user input the date field, the radio button will automatically fill as Closed

Comment: mysql_select_db($database_koneksi, $koneksi);
$query_inq = "SELECT * FROM inquiry";
$inq = mysql_query($query_inq, $koneksi) or die(mysql_error());
$row_inq = mysql_fetch_assoc($inq);
$totalRows_inq = mysql_num_rows($inq);

@Amessihel

Comment: There is no question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns for the current line an associative array pairing a column name with its value. You can check if a value is `NULL` (ie a column is not filled) with the function **`is_null()`**.

This answer is based on the code you posted in a comment:

```
$query_inq = "SELECT * FROM inquiry";
$inq = mysql_query($query_inq, $koneksi) or die(mysql_error());
$row_inq = mysql_fetch_assoc($inq);
$totalRows_inq = mysql_num_rows($inq)
```

Below we store in a **boolean variable** if the **status** is **closed**:

```
// Status is closed if $row_inq['status'] equals "Closed" **OR**
// the date thgl_selesai is filled 
$isClosedStatus =
  strcmp(htmlentities($row_inq['status'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'), "Closed") == 0 ||
  is_null($row_inq['tgl_selesai']);
```

(I assumed it was the case if the status in the base is set as "Closed" **OR** if the date `tgl_selesai` is filled; if it is not the case, editing the code is not very difficult.)

Finally, our HTML becomes:

```
<label>Status Inquiry:</label><br>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="Closed"
           <?php echo $isClodedStatus?"checked":"") ?>> Closed
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="On Progres"
           <?php echo $isClodedStatus?"":"checked") ?>> On Progres
</label>
```

As you can notice, using a variable makes the code above way easier to read.

**Note:** the official PHP manual [says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) that **`mysql_fetch_assoc`** is **deprecated** in PHP 5.5.0, and it was **removed** in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. Click on the link to read more about this issue.